# Video scrubber not stopping after scrubbing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've created a custom scrub bar which means the scrub handle is being drug along a specific axis. I can drag the handle just fine, but when I start dragging and move the mouse off the handle and release, the handle does not stop. I have to be over the actual handle when I stop dragging in order for it to stop.

That wouldn't be an issue, but the handle is pretty small so it would be nice if I could figure out a way to stop dragging the handle when the mouse is on or off.

A good example is Youtube. You can start dragging the handle and while moving the handle move your mouse off and release. The handle stops even though you're not releasing directly over it.

```
bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, scrubberDown);
bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, scrubberUp);

function scrubberDown(e:Event):void
{   
    flvPlayback.pause();
    var object = e.target;
    var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
        bounds.x = e.currentTarget.width - bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.width;
        bounds.y = e.currentTarget.y;
        bounds.width = bottom_bar.scrubber.width - (bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.width);
        bounds.height = bottom_bar.scrubber.height - bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.height; 
    object.startDrag(false, bounds);    
}

function scrubberUp(e:Event):void
{
    var _math:Number =((bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.x) / (960) * flvPlayback.totalTime);
    var object = e.target;
    object.stopDrag();
    flvPlayback.seek(_math);
    flvPlayback.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` in `scrubberDown` handler, and for the stage, so user can stop dragging in any position.

```
bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, scrubberDown);
//bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, scrubberUp);

function scrubberDown(e:Event):void {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, scrubberUp);

    //Your current code
}

function scrubberUp(e:Event):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, scrubberUp);

    var _math:Number =((bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.x) / (960) * flvPlayback.totalTime);
    bottom_bar.scrubber.handle.stopDrag();
    flvPlayback.seek(_math);
    flvPlayback.play();
}
```

Comment: Hey Nicolas, I tried your suggestion, but I get an error `ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property stopDrag not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value.
 at player_fla::MainTimeline/scrubberUp()`

Comment: That was it, something that simple had me researching for about two hours, lol. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Woohoo, you're over 1,000 now!